# Use of until with no second clause

Tags: clauses

The next fifteen minutes were the longest fifteen minutes in the world. Until the quiet was invaded by the distant sound of a car engine.

I found the above sentence in a novel. My question is can we use "until" in the start of a sentence with no second clause. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can.  The second sentence is not what we might call a "complete sentence", but in the context, it's acceptable.  It might be better, though, as "...in the world--until the quiet was invaded..." or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

"Until", in that context, is being used as a conjunction.  The two clauses "The next ... world" and "the quiet ... engine" are arguably "main clauses" -- they can stand separately as independent sentences -- but they are being joined together by a conjunction ("until") into a compound sentence.

However, as a matter of *style* the compound sentence is sometimes (as in this case) broken into two separate sentences at the conjunction.  (Ie, the first clause ends with `.` and the conjunction joining the second is capitalized.)  This is moderately common with conjunctions such as *however*, *although*, and *until* which imply a conditional connection between the two clauses.  This style (which is equivalent to a slightly longer than normal pause between the clauses in spoken English) serves to emphasize the significance of the second clause.